# zsh: command not found: I am installing appium but it always gives this as a result, how can I solve it

Tags: mobile, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R0Pf.png)
zsh: command not found: I am installing appium but it always gives this as a result, how can I solve it.

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

i tried these codes

Answer (score 0):

1.steps
uninstall appium and delete all files, remove paths you made related to appium.
2.steps
Uninstall node npm
3.steps
delete all node js files installed on the pc
4.steps
reinstall all uninstalled toolls in order

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).